# Filtering a set of letters from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to extract some vowels from an array using the .filte() method but the code doesn't continue on the next letters after finding instances of the first letter.The expected output is ['a','a','i'] but it only shows ['a','a']
Here is the code

```js
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
  const letters = s.toString().split("");
  console.log(letters);

  let vowels = letters.filter((letter) => {
    return letter.includes("a", "e", "i", "o", "u");
  });

  console.log(vowels);
}

vowelsAndConsonants("javascript");
```

Comment: It's [`includes(searchElement[, fromIndex])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), not `.includes(<arbritrary number of characters>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of getting the vowels

```js
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
  const letters = s.toString().split("");

  let vowels = letters.filter((letter) => {
    return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(letter) !== -1
  });

  console.log(vowels);
}

vowelsAndConsonants("javascript");
```

Comment: Thanks this worked

Answer (score 0):

The include method can only have one argument, see [this website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), the easiest way to test is by testing the value with an if :

```js
const vowels = letters.filter((letter) => {
    if (letter === "a" || letter === "e" || letter === "i" || letter === "o" || letter === "u" || letter === "y") 
        return (letter);
    return("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Regular Expression.

```js
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    const letters = s.toString().split("");
    console.log(letters);
  
    let vowels = letters.filter((letter) => {
        return /[aeiou]/.test(letter);
    });
  
    console.log(vowels);
    }
  
vowelsAndConsonants("javascript");
```

Answer (score 0):

Respecting your coding logic, I only fixed an issue with your `includes` usage :)

```js
const allVowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]; // what about "y" ?

function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
  const letters = s.toString().split("");
  console.log(letters);

  let vowels = letters.filter((letter) => {
    return allVowels.includes(letter);
  });

  console.log(vowels);
}

vowelsAndConsonants("javascript");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the letters into a `Map` and store the occurrences with a `Set`  or an `Array` (`[]`).

```js
const VOWELS = new Set('aeiou'.split(''));

const __charType = (ch) =>
  VOWELS.has(ch) ? 'vowels' : 'consonants';

const __resultTemplate = (unique = false) =>
  new Map(Object.entries({
    vowels: unique ? new Set() : [],
    consonants: unique ? new Set() : []
  }));

const vowelsAndConsonants = (str, unique = false) =>
  str.toLowerCase().split('').reduce((acc, ch) =>
    (key =>
      acc.set(key, unique
        ? acc.get(key).add(ch)
        : [...acc.get(key), ch]))
    (__charType(ch)),
    __resultTemplate(unique));

const test1 = vowelsAndConsonants('javascript');
console.log(`Vowels     : ${[...test1.get('vowels')].join(', ')}`);
console.log(`Consonants : ${[...test1.get('consonants')].join(', ')}`);

const test2 = vowelsAndConsonants('javascript', true);
console.log(`Vowels     : ${[...test2.get('vowels')].sort().join(', ')}`);
console.log(`Consonants : ${[...test2.get('consonants')].sort().join(', ')}`);
```